# Partial Text Search Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to discover all the persons named John that are in the cast of the collection show_info.
This works in the mongo shell.
`db.show_info.find({ 'cast': /john/i})`

But when I do this in python it won't work because I have to convert /john/i to a string.

This does not work in python using pymongo:

```
quote = {'cast': "/" + name + "/i"}
results = db.show_info.find(quote)
```

How can I make this query work in python using pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$regex`, see more in the [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
{
  "cast": {
    "$regex": "john",
    "$options": "i"
  }
}
```

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pu1xP6-FrUo)